# WordPress Flashes

Tags: wordpress, load

My Wordpress has a nasty white flashing going on everytime I load a page - Is there a fix for sort of things? It is a very lightweight page, so it's not a weight issue.

Thanks

Comment: If you are referring to the flash of a blank page as a new page loads, there are many factors to contend with.  It could be the browser, the speed of the internet connection, the speed/load of the server your Wordpress install is running on, etc.  It could also have to do with resources on the page being loaded from some other server, such as images or javascript files.  You haven't really given enough details to determine the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like FOUC, but we can't be sure, because you haven't posted a URL or any code.
See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fouc